# Why is window.location required for a select menu?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused and I want to understand the reason for window.location. If I create a link I don't need this, however if I set a value as a url in a select menu I need to use this, why? Is it because the anchor tag automatically does this and since select menus aren't designed for navigation they lack that build in functionality?or is there some other reason?

```
    var $select=$('<select></select>');
    var $option=$('<option></option>');
    var url= 'some url';
    $option.val(url);
    var button=$('<button></button>');
    button.click(fucntion(){
      window.location=$select.val();
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is because the anchor tag automatically does this and since select menus aren't designed for navigation they lack that build in functionality?

Yes. Anchor tags go to the specifed link by default, but the options of select don't. Anchor tags were designed to be the links; as for the selects - going to other pages is just not the primary reason they exist. So, if you want to implement the link-lke functionality, you have to use `window.location = ...`

Answer (score 0):

They're not designed for navigation, that's why. In fact they're not really a good tool to do navigation either.